# JFrame partly transparent

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Im working on analyse differences between shortest and simpliest way in a graph. To make it easier, I created a very simple JFrame for visualizing the graph and the way. As you can see on the pictue, the background seems to be partly transparent. I dont know the reason.

http://postimg.org/image/p1axfhj9h/ (Sory but i am not allowed to upload pictues, yet)

Is there a problem with the painting method? This problem occurs only on my private laptop. Im using java 1.7.0_45

I have noch changes made on background color or transparency. The paint method is only painting strings, ovals and lines.

```
public Drucker(Graph graph) {
    super();
    this.graph = graph;
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}


@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    for (int i = 0; i < this.graph.getKanten().size(); i++) {
        xxx
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < this.graph.getKnoten().size(); i++) {
        xxx
    }       

    this.paintDistance(g);
}
```

Is there a problem with my java vesion?
I home somebody can help me.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to [super construct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) your `paint()` method.

This simply means writing this:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    // your code goes here
}
```

When you super construct the method, that basically means you will paint the parent object then paint the String.

This is just a hunch. Let me know if this does, in fact, fix your problem.

Comment: That's a good hunch, I'd also be worried about the the OP overriding `paint` in the first place, but also probably overriding `paint` of top level container

Comment: You're right. That was the problem. Maybe i unintentionally removed this line. Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: Calling a super constructor using `super()` notation is different from calling a super method using `super.foo()` notation. The later has nothing to do with constructing on object.